# Linking Error - CMake 3.4.1 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile osgearth library with VS2010. The library uses CMake, so after setting all dependencies it generates a VS2010 solution file. However when running build in VS I get this linker error (and many other similar ones):

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: 无法打开输入文件“....\lib\Release\osgEarth.lib”

I'm not very familiar with osgEarth, is there anything else I have to set up?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, still for possible future search...

Obviously the Release build cannot find the `osgEarth.lib` library, the reason is most likely because of a problem in cmake. It generates libraries in Linker for VS like this: `optimized SOMELIB.lib debug SOMELIBd.lib`, which in most cases that `SOMELIB` was `zlib`.

So whether correct them one by one by going to the *Project Properties>Linker>Input*, or better, remove the trouble-making library when configuring and generating solution files in cmake . E.g. remove `zlibd.lib` entry from your cmake GUI, and then build for release.